# Are there any plans to transition Ubuntu on the Nexus 7 away from the Android kernel?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Will the Android kernel and underpinnings eventually go away? 
What are the plans for newer kernel releases?

Answer (score 5):

We currently use an Android 3.1 kernel so we can interface with the binary drivers for the Tegra3 chipset that nVidia provides.  We are currently working on merging this kernel with the official Ubuntu kernel.

This includes configuration and patches, assuming the patches can apply to a 3.1 kernel.  If newer kernels are released for the Nexus7 by Google, then we will investigate the effort in migrating our changes to the new version and release one if feasible.

Comment: sfeole, I don't know where exactly is the right place. but let me express that Ubuntu Touch is an outstanding piece of work. I have installed it on my N7 and I am really deeply impressed. congratulations and please go on. Where is the right platform to express my appreciation to the whole team?